# Does Windows offer virtual files?

Tags: windows, filesystems, cloud, virtualization

What I want to achieve is this: A program opens a file and reads it just like any file. But it's a virtual file which means that it isn't mapped to the local file system. Instead Windows sends a request to some web server at some ip address and port for the contents of the file and receives a response containing the file data. The program reading it doesn't notice, except for the delay.

Does this exist in Windows? The file is in the cloud, so to speak. If it exists, even on Win 8, how do I use this feature?

This is relevant:

https://github.com/owncloud/client/wiki/Virtual-Files-on-Windows-10

EDIT: I've found it! It's

Windows Projected File System (ProjFS)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system

That's it. Does anyone know how to use it?

Comment: WebDAV at least was supported, probably still is

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Perhaps, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not? It’s literally a request to a web server for a file and the programs don’t notice anything different. What exactly do you need that’s not handled by it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It's far too general and complicated. I think I've found it, see the edit above.

Comment: ProjFS is the answer to this question. If you have a new question, click the "Ask Question" button. "Does anyone know how to use xyz" is not a question that gets an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual files are managed extremely well by Nextcloud client on Windows.

It allows you to have all your files on a Nextcloud instance, and without taking any space unless needed, you just open the file you want and it gets downloaded automatically.

I have my own Nextcloud instance running on my own Ubuntu server and don't necessarily want to have all the files syncing to my Windows notebook - especially if I'm travelling. I can decide to choose which files and folders are virtual.

It looks like Nextcloud use **Dokan** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dokan_Library)  to manage virtual files, as **ProjFS** (mentioned in the question) is or was a relatively new system.
https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/issues/1104